# Can't display white div over image, can't align two divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, sidebar

I can't align two divs next to each other (.sidebar and .work-images) and also can't make .projects-section's white background to show over the image. I want each section to take up 100vh so this is the way it has to be.

Or if you didn't understand that, [on the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYdmJ.jpg) those three placeholder images should be next to the blue sidebar and the entire div that sidebar and images are contained in should have white background and should be over the image.

I also uploaded it to [github](https://skullscream.github.io/newportfolio/) but doubt it will be as good as on the screenshot because there's not responsiveness added.

```css
body {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: Questrial, sans-serif;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

/* About section */
.projects-section {
     height: 100vh;
}

#about {
     height: 100vh;
}

.background {
     width: 100%;
}

.about-heading {
     display: inline;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 22.5%;
     margin-left: 65%;
     color: white;
     width: 25%
}

span#h1 {
     font-size: 5em;
}

.about-heading p {
     font-size: 1em;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 1%;
}


/* Projects section */

.sidebar {
     background-color: #22a7f0;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 10%;
     position: relative;
}

.sidebar span {
     font-size: 5em;
     display: block;
     padding-top: .8em;
}

.sidebar a:link,
.sidebar a:visited {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
}

p#descr {
     color: white;
     font-size: 1.25em;
     padding-top: 5em;
}

/* End of sidebar */
.work-images {
     width: 90%;
}

.projects-section {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: white;
     height: 100vh;
}

.work-images img {
     width: 25%;
     margin-left: 2.5%;
     margin-right: 2.5%;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
          <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
          <title>Portfolio</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/b907bd4c71/Navigationicons/style.css">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
             $(function() {
               $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
                 if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                   var target = $(this.hash);
                   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                   if (target.length) {
                     $('html, body').animate({
                       scrollTop: target.offset().top
                     }, 1000);
                     return false;
                   }
                 }
               });
             });
             </script>
     </head>

     <!-- About section -->
     <section id="about">
          <div class="about-heading">
               <p><span id="h1">Hi!</span><br>Some text here. <br>Some more text.</p>
          </div>
          <img src="images/pexels-photo-48637.jpeg" alt="Background image" class="background">
     </section>

     <!-- Projects section -->
     <section id="projects">
          <div class="projects-section">
               <div class="sidebar">
                         <a href="#about"><span class="icon-home-green"></span></a>
                         <a href="#projects"><span class="icon-projects-green"></span></a>
                         <a href="#"><span class="icon-skills-green"></span></a>
                         <a href="#"><span class="icon-contact-green"></span></a>
                         <p id="descr">My work</p>
               </div>

               <div class="work-images">
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=154&txt=PROJECT&w=1440&h=900&txttrack=0" alt="PROJECT">
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=154&txt=PROJECT&w=1440&h=900&txttrack=0" alt="PROJECT">
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=154&txt=PROJECT&w=1440&h=900&txttrack=0" alt="PROJECT">
               </div>
          </div>
     </section>

     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding this to the .projects.section div:

```
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
```

But still didn't fix white background issue.

Answer (score -1):

Its a bad practice, try to work with bootstrap. But well, check if this helps.

```
#projects * {
   display:inline;
}
#siderbar * {
   display: block!important
}
```

Comment: I wanted to practice without bootstrap for a change. If it gets too tough I will use bootstrap here. Suggested fix doesn't work.